# Phonegap android - network.isReachable is not working?

Tags: android, exec, cordova

Recently I ran into another problem with PhoneGap. I try to use network.isReachable, but this method doesn't work for me. After debugging, I found that in phonegap.js in `Phonegap.exec()` is called `PluginManager.exec()`, which should return a value from Java code. For `network.isReachable` an empty value is returned, though. Next lines of code in Phonegap.exec() get executed only if result is not empty, but I get empty value returned for network.isReachable. What am I doing wrong? Please note, I am using phonegap version 0.9.3. on Android.

Answer (score 0):

network.isReachable takes a success callback as the second argument.

```
Network.prototype.isReachable = function(uri, callback, options)
```

Nothing is returned directly from the network.isReachable call, instead the callback is called with the network status value.